# Autofocus to a div so we can use arrow keys to scroll without having to click first

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with a few `<div>` containers.

How to give focus to one of them on page load, so that the user can use arrow keys to scroll (or even <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to scroll) without having to click on the `div` first?

I have tried:

```
<div id="main" autofocus>
```

but `autofocus` doesn't seem to work on non-input `div`.

_

This *could* be a solution but then the browser address bar would display the id http://example.com/#main which I don't want:

```
<body onload="location.hash = 'main';">
<div id="main">content</div>
</body>
```

_

Example: when you open https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page, you can immediately use <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> key or <kbd>Space</kbd> to scroll, without having to click anywhere.

Comment: "but autofocus doesn't seem to work on non-input div" - so far i know focus is only available in inputs, checkboxes, radios, selects, a's and textareas

Comment: How about just `onload="document.getElementById('main').click()"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to focus an element, and tabindex to allow the element to be focused.

```js
document.querySelector(".focus").focus();
```

```css
.focus {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
<div>Another div</div>
<div class="focus" tabindex="0">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<div>Bye</div>
```

Comment: @Basj focus is ment for mainly form and control elements, why would you want to focus it?

Comment: Maybe could you provide an html example with the scrolling div.

Comment: @Basj I am very happy to help people, but if you are not marking this as the right answer it doesn't help others that have the same question. And this particular question is answered. If it doesn't work in your own code ypou should look at my code sample again.

Comment: You're right @J.Meijer it solves the problem, and also [the one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339510/how-to-make-the-left-div-scrollable-with-space-bar-or-down-arrow-without-having).

Answer (score 1):

Focus events are used for input elements. Use `click` event instead:

```
document.querySelector('#main').click();
```

Also, make use of `tabindex` to bind keyboard events on non-input elements:

```
<div id="main" tabindex="0">main content</div>
```

Comment: The click doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens. After the click is triggered, I still can't scroll a div that has a scrollbar, when using up and down arrows or space bar.

Comment: You need to use keyboard events as we're not manually clicking but binding click event from the code itself.

Answer (score 1):

To focus on non input element you need `tabIndex` and use `focus` method.[**autofocus**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_autofocus.asp) works on selected set of element

```js
document.getElementById("main").focus()
```

```css
#main:focus {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" tabindex="1">hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need, first of all, to add a `tabindex="-1"` to `div#main` to make it programmatically focusable. Then with javascript get the div and make it focused.

Here's a snippet: make sure to add the code in `window.onload` event or to put your script tag directly before `</body>`

HTML: add tabindex attribute to `div#main`

```
<div id="main" tabindex="-1">
```

JavaScript: make `div#main` focused

```
document.getElementById("main").focus();
```

With that it will be automatically focused and still accept click event if you need to do some stuff when clicked, clean!

Hope I was able to put you further.