# How to make the left div scrollable with space bar or down arrow without having to click first?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

When you navigate on a page like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program), you can immediately use <kbd>SPACE BAR</kbd> or <kbd>UP/DOWN ARROW</kbd> or <kbd>PG UP/DOWN</kbd> to scroll the page, *without having to click on the background of the page first.*

**How to make that the following page also scrolls with these keys, without requiring a click on `#left` div first?** (see "live demo" link at the end of question)

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="topleft">LOGO</div>
        <div id="topright">TOPRIGHT</div>
        <div id="topmid">TOPMID</div>
    </div>

    <div id="mapcontainer"><div id="map"></div></div>

    <div id="left">
        <div id="leftmain">
            <div id="list">AAa<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { overflow: hidden; height: 100%; }
#left { height:calc(100% - 60px); width: 54%; float: left; padding: 0 2%; overflow-y: auto; }
#mapcontainer { height:100%; position: absolute; left: 58%; width: 42%; }
#map { height: 100%; }
#topleft { float: left; width: 155px; }
#topright { float: right; width: 50%; }
#header { height: 60px; background-color: #eee; }
```

I tried:

- with `tabindex="0"` on `#left` div but it doesn't work
- by triggering a click on `#left` div via JavaScript / jQuery with `$("#left").click()` but it doesn't work either.

Here is a [live demo](http://gget.it/ly4gtuj1/index.html).

Note: I didn't embed a SO code snippet (I tried) because when you click `Run`, it doesn't give focus to the page, so you have to click on the page anyway, so you cannot observe what I mean. It would be same problem with a jsfiddle.

Comment: Not sure if I correctly understand what you mean, but you have `overflow: hidden` on your body which prevents you from scrolling. Without it, scrolling works with the mentioned keys without clicking on the page first. (Firefox 59)

Comment: @Dominik The header should remain fixed and the right map should be fixed (using right half of the viewport), so it's only the `#left` div that should scroll. See [this updated page](http://gget.it/ly4gtuj1/index.html): the map won't load on the right (because of the missing API key) but you can see the placeholder on the right for the fixed map (that should not scroll when DOWN ARROW).

Comment: Remove body overflow:hidden

Comment: a div can't have a focus. have you tried to give higher z-order to #left ?

Comment: I first could not make the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49085086/1422096) work here, thus this question; but finally after many retries it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got you right. Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JLRxvM) with fixed header and fixed map.
This is achieved by using `position: fixed` on the header and map.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works indeed, but then the scrollbar is sticky on the right, which makes less sense when the right half of the viewport is a map (one would think that the scrollbar is ... for scrolling the map!) Also the scrollbar is present on top right, near the header, which is also non-conventional. Is there a way to adapt your Codepen to make the scrollbar in the middle, [like here](http://gget.it/ly4gtuj1/index.html)?